# What is the difference between pop() and pop()[0]?

Tags: python, arrays

I am leetcoding and implementing a stack when I saw the answer use a pop function using self.items.pop()[0].

```
def pop(self):
    if len(self.items) > 0:
        return self.items.pop()[0]
```

In this case does this simply do the same thing pop() does?

I understand that pop(x) will pop the value at the xth index. I would appreciate some examples of pop()[x].

Comment: That really depends on what the type of `self.items` is. Is it perhaps `list(some_dict.items())`?

Comment: It pops the last element (which apparently is an iterable) and returns the first element of the popped iterable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming, based on your phrasing, that `self.items` is a `list`.  The `pop` method for lists, as you've pointed out, can be used to remove and return an element of the list at a specified index.  If you omit the index, then the last item is removed and returned.

Either way, `pop` returns the item that was removed.  If you put `[0]` after the call to `pop`, you'll get the first item of the item that was popped.  So, if `self.items` is `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`, then `self.items.pop()` would be `[4, 5, 6]` and therefore `self.items.pop()[0]` would be `4`.

Comment: Yes this is exactly it thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can try it.

```
def pop(self):
if len(self.items) > 0:
    return self.items[1].pop(0)
```

Her items[1] is items[items list index]

items = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

Comment: What you've written isn't valid Python.  It also assumes that `len(self.items) >= 2`.

Comment: Daniel Walker you are right . I was just focusing on this part  self.items[1].pop(0) that's why I did not noticed it. Thanks for your response

Comment: Also, what does "items[items list index]" mean?